# How do i get dropdown's selected JSON category ID in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, for-loop

JASON response like this: I am showing services in dropdown...now i need selected `category_id`

```
{
 "result": {
     "data": [
         {
             "id": 167,
             "service_name": "Seo",
             "category_id": 1,
         },
         {
             "id": 166,
             "service_name": "Development",
             "category_id": 11,
         },
         {
             "id": 164,
             "service_name": "ghah",
             "category_id": 9,
         },
```

**EDIT:** swift class model for JSON response `AutoSearchResultModel`

```
public class AutoSearchResultModel {
public var result : AutoSearchResult?
 }
public class AutoSearchResult {
public var data : Array<SearchData>?
}
public class SearchData {
public var id : Int?
public var service_name : String?
public var category_id : Int?
}
```

**Code**: I am able to show result in dropdown and selected service name in textfield but i need selected `category_id` how ? if i give like this in for loop `selectedCategoryId = totData.category_id` all the time i am getting 11.. why? how do i get selected id

```
 var selectedCategoryId: String? = ""
 private var autosearchResult = AutoSearchResultModel(dictionary: NSDictionary())

 func autoSearchService(){
    
 APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: parameters as [String : Any], method: .post, url: CommonUrl.auto_search) { [weak self] (resp) in

     self?.autosearchResult = AutoSearchResultModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())

  }
 }


 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField:UITextField) {
 var testArray = [String]()
 var originalDataArray:[String] = Array()

         for totData in autosearchResult?.result?.data ?? []{
 
             originalDataArray.append(totData.service_name)
            selectedCategoryId = totData.category_id// all the time i am getting only 11.. how do i get selected category_id
         }

testArray.removeAll()
 if searchTF.text?.count != 0 {
     for totData in originalDataArray{

         if let wordToSearch = searchTF.text{
             let range = totData.lowercased().range(of: wordToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
             if range != nil {
                 testArray.append(totData)
             }
         }
     }
 }

 showDropDown(with: testArray, from: textField) { [weak self] (item, index) in
     
     self?.searchTF.text = item
     self?.searchResultService()

 }
 }
```

how do i get selected `category_id` please do guid me

Comment: what does AutoSearchResultModel look like?

Comment: @Vollan, I have edited my post with `AutoSearchResultModel `.. please check

Comment: still missing the `dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary()` part of your models

Comment: @Vollan, i have given like this `private var autosearchResult = AutoSearchResultModel(dictionary: NSDictionary())` above viewdidload... and i am using `autosearchResult` to get values

Comment: Why are you using two accounts when posting your questions, this one was already posted [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414291/how-do-i-get-selected-json-value-id-from-dropdown-array-in-swift).

Answer (score 0):

you have `selectedCategoryId = totData.category_id` inside the loop,
so you will always get the last `category_id` of your `autosearchResult?.result?.data`. The question is, which `category_id` do you want to select?

Move `selectedCategoryId` outside the `for loop`, and pick the one
you want using, for example something like:

```
if let result = autosearchResult?.result,
   let selectedCategoryId = result.data.first(where: {$0.category_id == x})
{
    print(selectedCategoryId)
}
```

EDIT1:

To use the textfield text for `category_id`, then use something like this:

```
if let result = autosearchResult?.result,
   let txt = textField.text,
   let catid = Int(txt),  // <-- convert to int
   let selectedCategoryId = result.data.first(where: {$0.category_id == catid})
{
    print(selectedCategoryId)
}
```

Since I don't have all your code info, you will have to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: if i move `selectedCategoryId = totData.category_id` outside for loop.. then how can i get selected `category_id `

Comment: i didn't understand your code

Comment: what does this mean `result.data.first(where: {$0.category_id == x})`

Comment: it means, from your array of data, pick the selected `category_id` you want. You have to decide which one you want, `x` is just a place value, for example, `123`.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to get selected category data.

```
func getCategoryData(data: [YourData], categoryID: Int) -> [YourModel] {
    // is you have converted your data into object 
    return data.filter({$0.category_id = categoryID})
    // if you have Dictionary 
    return data.filter({$0["category_id"] = categoryID})

}
```

you can use this as

```
var filterData = getCategoryData(data:originalDataArray, categoryID:2)
```

-> Some Suggestions you can you Codable object to convert you API Response to Object directly.